# NAudio Vorbis Mixing Exception

Tags: c#, naudio, mixing

I'm trying to figure out why NAudio is raising the following exception:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' 
occurred in NAudio.Vorbis.dll
Additional information: Specified argument out of range.
```

What I'm trying to do is creating a sort of fire and forget class for playing audios, here's the class:

```
public class FFSoundPlayer
{
    private readonly WaveOutEvent outputDevice;
    private WaveMixerStream32 mixer;
    private System.IO.Stream silenceStream;

    private FFSoundPlayer()
    {
        outputDevice = new WaveOutEvent();
        mixer = new WaveMixerStream32();

        System.Reflection.Assembly a = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        silenceStream = a.GetManifestResourceStream("ProperPath.silence.ogg");
        VorbisWaveReader wv = new VorbisWaveReader(silenceStream);
        LoopWaveStream silence = new LoopWaveStream(wv);

        mixer.AddInputStream(silence);
        mixer.AutoStop = false;

        outputDevice.Init(mixer);

        outputDevice.Play();
    }

    public static FFSoundPlayer Instance = new FFSoundPlayer();

    public void AddWave(WaveStream wave)
    {
        mixer.AddInputStream(wave);
    }
}
```

LoopWaveStream is just a WaveStream that reset the position when it reaches the end of the stream.

After I send a few files to thru the AddWave method I get the exception from NAudio. Any ideas? Am I doing it the proper way?

Thanks

Comment: Don't know if it'll help but seems like it's raising the exception when the streams I added end

Comment: Is there any InnerException?

Comment: @VisualVincent  It doesn't let me see exception details, all I get is unfortunately what I've posted

Comment: Okay? Well does it break on a specific line, or is it just thrown "in general"? Also have you checked so that you haven't set your IDE to always break on `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`?

Comment: @VisualVincent Since the exception comes from inside the vorbis dll I can not see the line and I'm not able to help you neither thru the call stack since it just show [external call] so I'd say it's "in general"

Comment: Will check for exception settings but I'd like to  know if it's me doing something wrong and then fix the code is causing the exception or if Naudio has gone crazy... the former probably anyway

Comment: I'd say your best option right now would be to download the [**NAudio source code**](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/tree/master/NAudio) and compile your own DLL from that. If you don't move that DLL anywhere (after compiling it) and reference it in your project, you should be able to see the source code when the application breaks.

Comment: So uninstall the packages from nuget and add the source code as project in my solution?

Comment: Or as a standalone solution. When you're done testing you can install the NuGet packages again and remove your own reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try and update this post later

Comment: NVorbis and NAudio.Vorbis are my projects.  Exceptions from NVorbis will include the full stack trace if you can example the exception itself from within the debugger or the catch handler that logged it.  If you can post the stack trace, I can take a look.  Better yet, post it to the NAudio.Vorbis issues page on GitHub, then link to the issue from here.